# Copy List & Label server content from DEV to QA to PROD

Tags: listlabel

Reproduce List & Label content in different environments.

I tried enabling List & Label API and use the methods, but input parameters need existing ParentFolderID, etc... which need to be explicitly created in server.

I am new with List & Label report server.
My requirement is to create all reports (data sources, etc...) in DEV server.
However to QA and PROD afterwards, there is a need to be able to 'export' all existing reports (data sources, etc...) from DEV.

My knowledge is more of Oracle BI Publisher.
In BIP server i have an option to download (zip) all the contents of a server folder (where i have all the reports) and i am able to log in another BIP server and upload the zipped file from original server.
This way i have exactly the same reports on all servers.

Is any sort of feature like it in List & Label report server?

Explicitly i need a kind of reports installer into List & Label report server.

Regards,

ccarvalho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, there is no such feature. The suggested procedure would be to copy the entire database from Dev to Production if your're working with the Report Server on both ends. Would that work for you?

Other than that, if you're designing your reports from a desktop app and want to transfer them to the Server, you could use the REST API of the Report Server. [Here](https://blog.combit.net/en/blog/development/10-2017/brand-new-component/) is a blog post covering the basics of this API. The setup also contains a sample ("C# Client API Sample").

Comment: Hello JBartau,

Thanks for reply.
I believe you understood my question, but i´m not sure i did fully understand your answer.
You´re saying to copy the entire DB from one environment to the other, but the report server is another one (is not the same) so how will the reports be available in the new environment, altougth the data is?

I am designing the reports layout with the combit provided tool (desktop combit report server designer).
Those are the reports (template+layout) i want to replicate in another server.

Comment: I´ve tested creating dataSource and Report Template using the api but i get errors "The specified folder for report templates does not exist or is invalid." and "No data provider typecode has been defined for the data source type of the external API: 'UnknownOrInternal'", respectively.

I have read the blog you provided, but it is not what i want, the use case is exporting (to any format, like pdf) to end user like a download to open the file, but not to import again into another report server elsewhere.

i do not know if it makes sense to you and/or if i made my self clear.

Comment: Please feel free to ask any further questions you need to know about.

Comment: Actually, the reports are stored alongside the config in the Report Server system database. It is this very database I'd simply clone to production to make this work. During setup you selected the server for the system database. Just export this with your favorite database management tool and import it to your production server. Adding an automatic import and export would make a great addition to https://forum.combit.net/c/idea-place.

Comment: Ok.To export a subset of the reports, for example, export from development environment, to the Production environment, do you have documentation of which tables need to be extracted and imported on the target database?

Comment: The relevant tables would be CmbtTemplateRepoItems  and CmbtTemplateRepoSnapshots. Due to consistency constraints, exporting and transferring a _single_ report this way would be hard. It would be better suited to copy all the reports from Dev to Production.